# Replace cursor with an HTML element

Tags: javascript, cursor

Using JavaScript, is it possible to replace the cursor with an HTML element (such as a div or canvas) instead of a custom image? It would be useful in some scenarios to replace the cursor with an HTML element other than an image, but I currently don't know of any way to do this.

Comment: For example, would it be possible to replace the cursor with an animated canvas element (or a table) instead of an image?

Comment: Table? It would be huge cursor!

Comment: @dfsq That would depend on the contents of the table. If the table only contained a few very small images, it wouldn't be huge at all.

Comment: This sounds like a fun project so I'm going to give it a whirl. It might be pretty complex to force the element to a certain position, but I certainly think it is possible.

Comment: @howderek I'm looking forward to seeing your solution to this problem. :)

Comment: @howderek One potential solution would be to make the cursor invisible, and then make an HTML element follow the cursor.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I am going to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution in jQuery, which you could see as an advantage or disadvantage. The reason I used jQuery is its cross-browser mouse position support and powerful + easy `.css` function.

#### The Code (Javascript)

```
var ElementCursor = {
    cursorElement: "",
    setCursor: function (cursorId) {
        $('html').css({
            'cursor': 'none',
        });
        ElementCursor.cursorElement = cursorId;
        ElementCursor.updateCursor();
    },
    removeCursor: function () {
        $('html').css({
            'cursor': ''
        });
        ElementCursor.cursorElement = '';
    },
    updateCursor: function () {
        $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
            $('#' + ElementCursor.cursorElement).css({
                'position': 'fixed',
                'user-select': 'none',
                'top': e.pageY + 2 + 'px',
                'left': e.pageX + 2 + 'px'
            });
        });
    }
};

ElementCursor.setCursor("cursor");
```

After you add that to your Javascript, you can simply call `ElementCursor.setCursor(id_of_your_cursor_element_here)` and it will automagically replace the cursor with that element. Don't want that cursor anymore? Call `ElementCursor.removeCursor()` and be on your way.

Comment: I notice that the cursor still appears (in the latest version of Google Chrome, on Windows 7) whenever I hold down and drag the mouse. I wonder if it's possible to fix this.

Comment: @AndersonGreen Unfortunately, it appears the only way to do that would be to prevent text selection all togther by using `return false` on the `onmousedown` event. Here's an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/mCgmP/9/

Comment: Is it possible to allow text to be selected by the custom cursor? I've noticed that highlighting text with the custom cursor doesn't work as expected. It appears that the custom cursor [overlaps slightly with the text that I'm trying to select](http://jsfiddle.net/mCgmP/10/), so it might be necessary to offset the cursor slightly from the mouse position.

Comment: @AndersonGreen I prevented the selection of text within the cursor and added an offset: http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/mCgmP/

Comment: The highlighting still doesn't work properly when an image is used as a cursor. Perhaps the offset should be automatically adjusted depending on the height of the cursor, instead of being set to 20 pixels. http://jsfiddle.net/mCgmP/14/

Answer (score 1):

If by replace you mean change the image of the cursor with an HTML element, then no -- [here's how the cursor CSS property works.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp)

What you could do is hide the cursor, and have an absolute position element that follows the cursor around.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("body").mousemove(function(event){
                $("#cursor").css("left", event.pageX)
                $("#cursor").css("top", event.pageY)
            })
        })
    </script>
    </head>
    <body style="cursor:none">
    <div id="cursor" style="position:absolute">hello</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**
I forgot:

```
cursor: none;
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <canvas id="mycanvas" width="50" height="50"></canvas>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#mydiv
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width:1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: red;
}

#mycanvas
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function Thing(x, y)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

var mousePos = new Thing(0, 0);

mydiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
mycanvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");

mydiv.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event)
{
    mousePos.x = event.clientX;
    mousePos.y = event.clientY;

    mycanvas.style.top = mousePos.y + "px";
    mycanvas.style.left = mousePos.x + "px";
    console.log(mycanvas.style);
}, false);
```

[You can play with it here](http://jsfiddle.net/n4V23/)

Comment: Change `position: absolute;` to `position: fixed` so it will work with scrolling: http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/n4V23/2/

Comment: @howderek I think this answer should be edited to reflect the corrections you have made. :)

Comment: This works with other types of HTML elements as well. http://jsfiddle.net/n4V23/3/